# MySQL search array without PHP

Tags: mysql, arrays

I want to search an array in MySQL without PHP but all the examples I found were with PHP. Here is my procedure:

```
BEGIN
     DECLARE indx INT default 0;
     DECLARE y INT default 0;
     UPDATE radios SET geoblocking_enabled = in_enabledgeoblocking WHERE id = in_radioid;
     DELETE FROM geoblocking WHERE assigned_radioid = in_radioid;
     SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(in_geoblockingjson ,'$.countries');
     SET indx = JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(in_geoblockingjson ,'$.countries'));
     REPEAT
     INSERT INTO geoblocking (country, countryindex) VALUES (JSON_EXTRACT(in_geoblockingjson, CONCAT("$[", indx, "].countries")), JSON_EXTRACT(in_geoblockingjson, CONCAT("$[", indx, "].countryindexes")));
     SET y = y + 1;
     UNTIL y = indx
     END REPEAT;
END
```

For some reason it inserts the data but with NULL values.. here is what I used for my example request:

[image: Example request params]

Comment: MySQL have no ARRAY datatype. Be more precise. The best way - provide sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) and desired output.

Comment: If this table is of non-trivial size this will be extremely punishing to run since it will likely have to decode every row's JSON in order to test for matches.

Comment: @Akina As soon as there is no array datatype there is no reason for me to keep trying, I will just put the array inside a record in my table and let the NodeJS do the rest.. thank you for your answer

Comment: @tadman I was thinking about what would be better just to store the array as an array or to store everything separately in a different table. But as I told in my previous comment, there is no option. Thank you for your answer

Comment: *As soon as there is no array datatype there is no reason for me to keep trying* MySQL have JSON datatype which can store JSON array. Moreover, if array elements are integers you may build multi-valued index by this column...